# rails caching: expire_action in another namespace in json format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have a json api where i perform action caching :

```
class Api::V2::TagsController < Api::V2::BaseController

  before_filter :set_cache_headers, :only => [:categories, :tribes]
  caches_action :categories, :tribes, :expires_in => 1.hour
```

The only way i found to expire this cache is to use :

```
Rails.cache.delete api_v2_categories_url(:locale => nil)+'.json?'
```

**This is terribly ugly**

Please can anyone help me improve this terrible hack ?

---

More informations :

Caching works great and i see cache writes in logs :

> `Cache write: http://localhost:3000/api/v2/categories.json?`

In an admin namespace i need to expire the cache, i've tried :

expire_action(:controller => '/api/v2/tags', :action => 'categories', :format => :json)

Which fails and outputs :

> Expire fragment
>   views/localhost:3000/mu-8c54ade2-cbb77ba0-4f0c28d3-607169d0.json?action=categories&controller=api/v2/tags&locale=fr

P.S: I've tried this answer without success: [rails caching: expire_action in another namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082181/rails-caching-expire-action-in-another-namespace)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new route in your api called clear_categories and in it call

```
expire_action :action => :categories
```

Then in your admin just hit that route.  You could also redirect back to the calling admin page by passing a redirect url to clear_categories or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and fixed it using something like below,

```
expire_fragment(ActionCachePath.new(self, {
    :controller => '/api/v2/tags',
    :action => 'categories'
}, true).path)
```